# How to write a function to multiply with two sets of radiobuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've written this code:

```
from tkinter import *
o=Tk()
v1=IntVar()
v2=IntVar()

p1=Radiobutton(o, text='1', variable=v1, value=1)
p1.grid(row=0, column=1)
d1=Radiobutton(o, text='1', variable=v2, value=1)
d1.grid(row=1, column=0)

p2=Radiobutton(o, text='2', variable=v1, value=2)
p2.grid(row=0, column=2)
d2=Radiobutton(o, text='2', variable=v2, value=2)
d2.grid(row=2, column=0)

p3=Radiobutton(o, text='3', variable=v1, value=3)
p3.grid(row=0, column=3)
d3=Radiobutton(o, text='3', variable=v2, value=3)
d3.grid(row=3, column=0)

p4=Radiobutton(o, text='4', variable=v1, value=4)
p4.grid(row=0, column=4)
d4=Radiobutton(o, text='4', variable=v2, value=4)
d4.grid(row=4, column=0)

p5=Radiobutton(o, text='5', variable=v1, value=5)
p5.grid(row=0, column=5)
d5=Radiobutton(o, text='5', variable=v2, value=5)
d5.grid(row=5, column=0)

w=Label(o, text='0')
w.place(x=90, y=60)
w.config(font=("Arial", 30), foreground="magenta")
o.mainloop()
```

My goal is to use these two sets of radiobuttons as multipliers, and a result would be shown withing label. My main issue is that I do not know how would I extract value attached to two of the picked radiobuttons and multiply them within function which would return result printed inside label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
from tkinter import *

def updateLabel():
    w.config(text = str(v1.get()*v2.get()))

o=Tk()
v1=IntVar()
v2=IntVar()

for i in range(1,6):
    Radiobutton(o, text = str(i), variable = v1, value = i, command = updateLabel).grid(row=0,column=i)
    Radiobutton(o, text = str(i), variable = v2, value = i, command = updateLabel).grid(row=i,column=0)

w=Label(o, text='0')
w.place(x=90, y=60)
w.config(font=("Arial", 30), foreground="magenta")
o.mainloop()
```

The key here is to set the `command` option equal to a function to call when a radiobutton selection is changed. Note that you don't need to keep the references to the radio buttons around since you don't do anything with the radio buttons after you make them. Interacting with them is done solely through the `v1` and `v2` variables.